# Dynamically Create a generic type for template

Tags: c#, generics

I'm programming WCF using the ChannelFactory which expects a type in order to call the CreateChannel method. For example:

```
IProxy proxy = ChannelFactory<IProxy>.CreateChannel(...);
```

In my case I'm doing routing so I don't know what type my channel factory will be using. I can parse a message header to determine the type but I hit a brick wall there because even if I have an instance of Type I can't pass that where ChannelFactory expects a generic type.

Another way of restating this problem in very simple terms would be that I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
string listtype = Console.ReadLine(); // say "System.Int32"
Type t = Type.GetType( listtype);
List<t> myIntegers = new List<>(); // does not compile, expects a "type"
List<typeof(t)> myIntegers = new List<typeof(t)>(); // interesting - type must resolve at compile time?
```

Is there an approach to this I can leverage within C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What you are looking for is MakeGenericType

```
string elementTypeName = Console.ReadLine();
Type elementType = Type.GetType(elementTypeName);
Type[] types = new Type[] { elementType };

Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type genericType = listType.MakeGenericType(types);
IProxy  proxy = (IProxy)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

So what you are doing is getting the type-definition of the generic "template" class, then  building a specialization of the type using your runtime-driving types.

Comment: We can actually just call `listType.MakeGenericType(elementType)` - it's `params` argument.

Answer (score 8):

You should look at this post from Ayende: [WCF, Mocking and IoC: Oh MY!](http://www.ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/02/10/WCF-Mocking-and-IoC-Oh-MY.aspx).  Somewhere near the bottom is a method called GetCreationDelegate which should help.  It basically does this:

```
string typeName = ...;
Type proxyType = Type.GetType(typeName);

Type type = typeof (ChannelFactory<>).MakeGenericType(proxyType);

object target = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("CreateChannel", new Type[] {});

return methodInfo.Invoke(target, new object[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a question: Do you *really* need to create a channel with the exact contract type in your specific case?

Since you're doing routing, there's a very good chance you could simply deal with the generic channel shapes. For example, if you're routing a one-way only message, then you could create a channel to send the message out like this:

```
ChannelFactory<IOutputChannel> factory = new ChannelFactory<IOutputChannel>(binding, endpoint);
IOutputChannel channel = factory.CreateChannel();
...
channel.SendMessage(myRawMessage);
```

If you needed to send to a two-way service, just use IRequestChannel instead.

If you're doing routing, it is, in general, a lot easier to just deal with generic channel shapes (with a generic catch-all service contract to the outside) and just make sure the message you're sending has all the right headers and properties.

Comment: I had a dilemma marking the "answer" to my question. In terms of using WCF, I was able to use this technique you mention and it works like a charm (thank you!). I chose the above since it does technically answer the question I'd asked (even if this is a better way).