# Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

The title is kind of obscure. What I want to know is if this is possible:

```
string typeName = <read type name from somwhere>;
Type myType = Type.GetType(typeName);

MyGenericClass<myType> myGenericClass = new MyGenericClass<myType>();
```

Obviously, MyGenericClass is described as:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>
```

Right now, the compiler complains that 'The type or namespace 'myType' could not be found." There has got to be a way to do this.

Comment: Generics != templates.  All generic type variables are resolved at compile time and not at runtime.  This is one of those situations where the 'dynamic' type of 4.0 may be useful.

Comment: @Will - in what way? When used with generics, under the current CTP you essentially end up calling the <object> versions (unless I'm missing a trick...)

Comment: @MarcGravell you can use `foo.Method((dynamic)myGenericClass)` for run time method binding, effectively the service locator pattern for a type's method overloads.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic yes, for some generic `public void Method<T>(T obj)` - a trick I've used more than a few times in the last 6 years since that comment ;p

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can't do this without reflection. However, you *can* do it with reflection. Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Generic<T>
{
    public Generic()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("T={0}", typeof(T));
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string typeName = "System.String";
        Type typeArgument = Type.GetType(typeName);

        Type genericClass = typeof(Generic<>);
        // MakeGenericType is badly named
        Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgument);

        object created = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedClass);
    }
}
```

Note: if your generic class accepts multiple types, you must include the commas when you omit the type names, for example:

```
Type genericClass = typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>);
Type constructedClass = genericClass.MakeGenericType(typeArgument1, typeArgument2);
```

Comment: OK, this is good, but how does one go about calling methods on created? More reflection?

Comment: Well, if you can get away with making your generic type implement a non-generic interface, you can cast to that interface. Alternatively, you could write your own generic method which does all of the work you want to do with the generic, and call *that* with reflection.

Comment: (You then wouldn't have to call MakeGenericType etc, because constructing the instance of the generic type would be done inside the generic method too.)

Comment: Yeah, I dont undertand how to use created if the only info you have about the type returned is in the typeArgument type variable? It seems to me like you would have to cast to that variable, but you dont know what it is so Im not sure if you can do that with reflection. Another question if the object is for example of type int if you pass it as an object variable into say fro example a List<int> wil this work? will the variable created be treated as an int?

Comment: @jimioh: Yes, if you call a method with reflection and it takes a value type parameter, the argument will be unboxed on the way in. You're right that you'd need to cast the created object elsewhere, but often that's okay.

Comment: @RobertC.Barth You can also make the "created" object in the example type "dynamic" instead of "object".  That way you can call methods on it, and evaluation will be deferred until runtime.

Comment: what about generic methods?

Comment: @balanza: You use MakeGenericMethod.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately no there is not.  Generic arguments must be resolvable at Compile time as either 1) a valid type or 2) another generic parameter.  There is no way to create generic instances based on runtime values without the big hammer of using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional how to run with scissors code. Suppose you have a class similar to

```
public class Encoder() {
public void Markdown(IEnumerable<FooContent> contents) { do magic }
public void Markdown(IEnumerable<BarContent> contents) { do magic2 }
}
```

Suppose at runtime you have a **FooContent**

*If* you were able to bind at compile time you would want

```
var fooContents = new List<FooContent>(fooContent)
new Encoder().Markdown(fooContents)
```

*However* you cannot do this at runtime. To do this at runtime you would do along the lines of:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
var dynamicList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
((IList)dynamicList).Add(fooContent);
```

To dynamically invoke `Markdown(IEnumerable<FooContent> contents)`

```
new Encoder().Markdown( (dynamic) dynamicList)
```

Note the usage of `dynamic` in the method call. At runtime `dynamicList` will be `List<FooContent>` (additionally also being `IEnumerable<FooContent>`) since even usage of dynamic is still rooted to a strongly typed language the run time binder will select the appropriate `Markdown` method. If there is no exact type matches, it will look for an object parameter method and if neither match a runtime binder exception will be raised alerting that no method matches.

The obvious draw back to this approach is a huge loss of type safety at compile time. Nevertheless code along these lines will let you operate in a very dynamic sense that at runtime is still fully typed as you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

My requirements were slightly different, but will hopefully help someone. I needed to read type from a config and instantiate the generic type dynamically.

```
namespace GenericTest
{
    public class Item
    {
    }
}

namespace GenericTest
{
    public class GenericClass<T>
    {
    }
}
```

Finally, here is how you call it. [Define the type with a backtick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var t = Type.GetType("GenericTest.GenericClass`1[[GenericTest.Item, GenericTest]], GenericTest");
var a = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what types will be passed you can do this without reflection. A switch statement would work. Obviously, this would only work in a limited number of cases, but it'll be much faster than reflection.

```
public class Type1 { }

public class Type2 { }

public class Generic<T> { }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var typeName = nameof(Type1);

        switch (typeName)
        {
            case nameof(Type1):
                var type1 = new Generic<Type1>();
                // do something
                break;
            case nameof(Type2):
                var type2 = new Generic<Type2>();
                // do something
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this gets ugly fast once you start dealing with 100s of classes.

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet I want to show how to create and use a dynamically created list. For example, I'm adding to the dynamic list here.

```
void AddValue<T>(object targetList, T valueToAdd)
{
    var addMethod = targetList.GetType().GetMethod("Add");
    addMethod.Invoke(targetList, new[] { valueToAdd } as object[]);
}

var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { dynamicType }); // dynamicType is the type you want
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

AddValue(list, 5);
```

Similarly you can invoke any other method on the list.