# How do I detect that an object is a generic collection, and what types it contains?

Tags: c#, generics, typechecking

I have a string serialization utility that takes a variable of (almost) any type and converts it into a string.  Thus, for example, according to my convention, an integer value of 123 would be serialized as "i:3:123" (i=integer; 3=length of string; 123=value).

The utility handles all primitive type, as well as some non-generic collections, like ArrayLists and Hashtables.  The interface is of the form

`public static string StringSerialize(object o) {}`

and internally I detect what type the object is and serialize it accordingly.

Now I want to upgrade my utility to handle generic collections.  The funny thing is, I can't find an appropriate function to detect that the object is a generic collection, and what types it contains - both of which pieces of information I need in order to serialize it correctly.  To date I've been using coding of the form

`if (o is int) {// do something}`

but that doesn't seem to work with generics.

What do you recommend?

---

EDIT: Thanks to [Lucero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755200/how-do-i-detect-that-an-object-is-a-generic-collection-and-what-types-it-contain/755217#755217), I've gotten closer to the answer, but I'm stuck at this little syntactical conundrum here:

```
if (t.IsGenericType) {
  if (typeof(List<>) == t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) {
    Type lt = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    List<lt> x = (List<lt>)o;
    stringifyList(x);
  }
}
```

This code doesn't compile, because "`lt`" is not allowed as the `<T>` argument of a `List<>` object.  Why not?  And what is the correct syntax?

Comment: You cant use lt because its runtime type information, not compile time.. (which generics uses), why do you even want to create a generic list this way anyway? it seems very pointless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-systemtype-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class - here's how you need to do this if you REALLY want to go this way, but to me I think you may be missing the point of generics.

Comment: @meandmycode - it is perfectly normal for serialization utility code.

Comment: Also - have you considered things like Json.NET, protobuf-net, etc - pre-rolled serialization libraries...

Comment: I don't see why, for deserialization perhaps- but why you would instanciate dynamically at serialization.

Comment: @meandmycode - I meant the approach; nowhere in the code does it create a list, so I'm not sure what your point is...

Comment: My point is theres no reason to need to cast a generic list for serialization, all you would care about is enumerating a sequence of objects.

Comment: You generally need to know what the list-type is to do that serialization... checking individual objects is not ideal.

Comment: Well thats arguable because each concrete type may have its own serialization, but still theres no reason that you need to do the (List<lt>) part, the initial question to get the type argument of the generic list would be enough.

Comment: @meandmycode - so you never move code out into separate methods? Calling a generic method (with the generic args chosen at runtime) requires this approach. And re serialization: *regardless* of the actual types (maybe derived) in the list, you often need to know the actual list type; this can...

Comment: ...be key to the serialization strategy. The list type, might, for example, influence the discriminator used to identify the different concrete types.

Comment: Clearly you are intent on missing the point, so I'm not going to to bother, and I don't think its fair to clutter this question.. needless to say my original point was about trying to get to root problem.

Comment: @meandmycode - no, quiet the contrary; you are just choosing to ignore the fact that *the list type sometimes matters* (i.e. the T in IList<T>). Having spent a lot of time writing utility serialization code, I know this for fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re your conundrum; I'm assuming `stringifyList` is a generic method? You would need to invoke it with reflection:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("stringifyList")
            .MakeGenericMethod(lt).Invoke({target}, new object[] {o});
```

where `{target}` is `null` for a static method, or `this` for an instance method on the current instance.

Further - I wouldn't assume that all collections are a: based on `List<T>`, b: generic types. The important thing is: **do they implement `IList<T>` for some `T`**?

Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program {
    static Type GetListType(Type type) {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfaces()) {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)) {
                return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    static void Main() {
        object o = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Type t = o.GetType();
        Type lt = GetListType(t);
        if (lt != null) {
            typeof(Program).GetMethod("StringifyList")
                .MakeGenericMethod(lt).Invoke(null,
                new object[] { o });
        }
    }
    public static void StringifyList<T>(IList<T> list) {
        Console.WriteLine("Working with " + typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc!  But help me understand please - why do we have to resort to reflection?  Isn't there some way of calling StringifyList that the compiler will understand?  Why doesn't MS allow you to declare a List<> of type List<lt>?

Comment: There is no such way. MakeGenericMethod and MakeGenericType are the only options if you want to use generics with types resolved at runtime.

Comment: Hummm.  "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true."  Did you get your code to run?

Comment: The example? Yes; it outputs "Working with Int32" - I've just double checked.

Comment: @Shaul, how did you solve that "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true." problem. I am having difficulties trying to correct this InvalidOperationException. Thanks @Marc Gravell.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I am trying to call the extension method ElementAt that is implemented by System.Linq.Enumerable.

Comment: @Fabio - in the example, `stringifyList` was a generic method. `ElementAt`. Re `ElementAt` - can you clarify what you *do* have? i.e. what the context is here?

Answer (score 7):

Use the Type to gather the required information.

For generic objects, call GetType() to get their type and then check `IsGenericType` to find out if it is generic at all. If it is, you can get the generic type definition, which can be compared for instance like this: `typeof(List<>)==yourType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`.
To find out what the generic types are, use the method `GetGenericArguments`, which will return an array of the types used.

To compare types, you can do the following: `if (typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(yourGenericTypeArgument))`.

---

EDIT to answer followup:

Just make your `stringifyList` method accept an `IEnumerable` (not generic) as parameter and maybe also the known generic type argument, and you'll be fine; you can then use `foreach` to go over all items and handle them depending on the type argument if necessary.

Comment: Good answer, thanks - but I'm just missing one little syntactical trick: how do I cast from object o to List<TheType>?

Comment: Assuming that all collections are a: generic, or b: related to List<T> is risky. I could write my own FooCollection : IList<Foo> that is neither.

Comment: You don't really need to cast this, just use the non-generic IEnumerable (e.g. just do a foreach on the class). Or, if you did check that the generic type argument matches, you can of course also do a hard cast, e.g. IList<int> when the IsAssignableFrom sample above returned true.

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level, all generic lists implement `IEnumerable<T>`, which is in itself a descendant of `IEnumerable`. If you want to serialize a list, then you could just cast it down to IEnumerable and enumerate the generic objects inside them.

The reason why you can't do

```
Type lt = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
List<lt> x = (List<lt>)o;
stringifyList(x);
```

is because generics still need to be statically strong typed, and what you're trying to do is to create a dynamic type. `List<string>` and `List<int>`, despite using the same generic interface, are two completely distinct types, and you can't cast between them.

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
List<string> strList = intList; // error!
```

What type would `stringifyList(x)` receive? The most basic interface you could pass here is `IEnumerable`, since `IList<T>` doesn't inherit from `IList`.

To serialize the generic list, you need to keep information on the original Type of the list so that you can re-create with `Activator`. If you want to optimize slightly so that you don't have to check the type of each list member in your stringify method, you could pass the Type you've extracted from the list directly.

Answer (score -1):

I did not want to accept that there is no way to cast to `List<lt>`. So I came up with using a `List<dynamic>`.

But since i need it for all types of IEnumerables, my solution looks like this:

```
object o = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                     .Select(x => new MyClass { Name = $"Test {x}" });
                     //.ToList();
                     //.ToArray();

if (o.IsIEnumerableOfType<IHasName>(out var items))
{
    // here you can use StringifyList...
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}


static class Ext
{
    public static bool IsIEnumerableOfType<T>(this object input, 
                                              [NotNullWhen(true)] out IEnumerable<T>? values)
    {
        var innerType = input.GetType()
                             .GetInterfaces()
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => 
                                     x.IsGenericType
                                     && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))?
                             .GetGenericArguments()[0];

        if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(innerType))
        {
            values = ((IEnumerable<object>)input).OfType<T>();
            return true;
        }
        
        values = null;
        return false;
    }
}



class MyClass : IHasName
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

**Features:**

- You can use any Type of IEnumerable (inkl. Arrays and Lists)
- Your can not only specify the actual class but its interface
- It does not give any warnings due to the use of `[NotNullWhen(true)]`

**Update:**

For Dictionaries it's nearly the same code. Just change `IEnumerable` to `IDictionary` and use

```
Type keyType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type valueType = t.GetGenericArguments()[1];
```

to get the key and value type.

**Update based on @Enigmativity comments**

> The use of `dynamic` is not needed. `object` is fine and is safer.
> – Enigmativity

Yes, you can use `IEnumerable<object>` in this case.

> You also only need this test: `if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(input.GetType()))`. –
> Enigmativity

> And, when you really get down to it you can just write `if (o is IEnumerable<IHasName> items)` in the main code.  – Enigmativity

This only works for `IEnumerable`, but if you want to work with a list and the list should be of type `IList<IHasName>` It will not work anymore. So my solution is more versatile. (The accepted answer uses IList and inspired me)

I tried this with a List and it did not enter the if-statement:

```
object x = new List<MyClass>();
if (x is IList<IHasName> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = newItems.ElementAt(i);
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
if (value.IsListOfType<UpdatableBase>(out var list))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        list[i] = newItems.ElementAt(i);
    }
}
```

The extension methode looks like:

```
public static bool IsListOfType<T>(this object input, [NotNullWhen(true)] out IList<T>? values)
{
    Type? innerType = input.GetType()
                            .GetInterfaces()
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => 
                                   x.IsGenericType
                                   && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))?
                            .GetGenericArguments()[0];

    if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(innerType))
    {
        values = ((IList<object>)input).OfType<T>().ToList();
        return true;
    }

    values = null;
    return false;
}
```

> But, finally, this question is about using a run-time type, not a
> compile time one. –  Enigmativity

My solution is suitable for the use case described in the question. He can use `object` or what ever (base) type his serializer is able to stringify as T-parameter.

Comment: The use of `dynamic` is not needed. `object` is fine and is safer.

Comment: You also only need this test: `if (typeof(IEnumerable<object>).IsAssignableFrom(input.GetType()))`.

Comment: And, when you really get down to it you can just write `if (o is IEnumerable<IHasName> items)` in the main code.

Comment: But, finally, this question is about using a run-time type, not a compile time one.

Comment: Thanks for your imediate feedback. I've updated my answer according to your feedback.

Comment: You understand that the question is about having a run-time type of `Type lt` and how to call a generic method with it. Your answer has a compile-time type `IHasName` so it does not answer the question.