# How do I check if a given value is a generic list?

Tags: c#, reflection, list, generics

```
public bool IsList(object value)
    {
        Type type = value.GetType();
        // Check if type is a generic list of any type
    }
```

What's the best way to check if the given object is a list, or can be cast to a list?

Comment: Maybe you find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755200/how-do-i-detect-that-an-object-is-a-generic-collection-and-what-types-it-contain

Answer (score 121, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;

if(value is IList && value.GetType().IsGenericType) {

}
```

Comment: This does not work - I get the following exception - value is IList Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' requires '1' type arguments

Comment: You need to add using System.Collections; on top of your source file. The IList interface I suggested is NOT the generic version (hence the second check)

Comment: You're right. This works like a charm. I was testing this in my Watch window and forgot all about the missing namespace. I like this solution better, very simple

Comment: This doesn't work. I would guess in 4.0 IList<T> != IList? Anyway, I had to check if it was generic and IEnumerable, and then check for the existence of the property I wanted to check, "Count". I suppose this weakness is partly why WCF turns all of your List<T>'s into T[].

Comment: @user1086498  this is not a weakness of WCF.  if you look at your service Reference advanced tab you can select Generic list instead of array

Comment: @Edza Incorrect. This *usually* works since `List<T>` and `ObservableCollection<T>` implement `IList`.

Comment: That is actually not accurate solution. `Foo<T> : IList != IList<T>`

Answer (score 158):

For you guys that enjoy the use of extension methods:

```
public static bool IsGenericList(this object o)
{
    var oType = o.GetType();
    return (oType.IsGenericType && (oType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)));
}
```

So, we could do:

```
if(o.IsGenericList())
{
 //...
}
```

Comment: For .Net Core this needs to be modified slightly to `return oType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && oType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);`

Comment: Works like a charm! If you only have the type not the object this will work for you! Thanks!!

Comment: Would checking for `IList<>` instead be safer?

Answer (score 17):

```
 bool isList = o.GetType().IsGenericType 
                && o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>));
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's an implementation that works in .NET Standard, and works against interfaces:

```
    public static bool ImplementsGenericInterface(this Type type, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return type
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .ImplementedInterfaces
            .Any(x => x.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType);
    }
```

And here are the tests (xunit):

```
    [Fact]
    public void ImplementsGenericInterface_List_IsValidInterfaceTypes()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        Assert.True(list.GetType().ImplementsGenericInterface(typeof(IList<>)));
        Assert.True(list.GetType().ImplementsGenericInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>)));
        Assert.True(list.GetType().ImplementsGenericInterface(typeof(IReadOnlyList<>)));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ImplementsGenericInterface_List_IsNotInvalidInterfaceTypes()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        Assert.False(list.GetType().ImplementsGenericInterface(typeof(string)));
        Assert.False(list.GetType().ImplementsGenericInterface(typeof(IDictionary<,>)));
        Assert.False(list.GetType().ImplementsGenericInterface(typeof(IComparable<>)));
        Assert.False(list.GetType().ImplementsGenericInterface(typeof(DateTime)));
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public bool IsList(object value) {
    return value is IList 
        || IsGenericList(value);
}

public bool IsGenericList(object value) {
    var type = value.GetType();
    return type.IsGenericType
        && typeof(List<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on Victor Rodrigues' answer, we can devise another method for generics. In fact, the original solution can be reduced to only two lines:

```
public static bool IsGenericList(this object Value)
{
    var t = Value.GetType();
    return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
}

public static bool IsGenericList<T>(this object Value)
{
    var t = Value.GetType();
    return t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<T>);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the following code:

```
public bool IsList(Type type) => type.IsGenericType && (
            (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
            || (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
            );
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(value is IList && value.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: I think you need a call to GetType() e.g. value.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Length > 0

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way would be to do something like this:

```
IList list = value as IList;

if (list != null)
{
    // use list in here
}
```

This will give you maximum flexibility and also allow you to work with many different types that implement the `IList` interface.

Comment: this does not check if it a *generic* list as asked.