# How to cast a generic Type T to a List of a specific type

Tags: c#, generics, casting, generic-list

I have a method that takes as an argument a generic Type T. If T is of Type List, I would like to cast it to a List where Y is the type of element contained in T. I suspect I am misunderstanding the constraints of generic Types but any help would be appreciated.

Example:

```
public void MapData<T>(T genericData)
{
   var genericDataType = genericData.GetType();

   if (genericDataType.Name.Contains("List"))
   {
      //Cast T to a List containing the type of elements contained in T
   }
 }
```

I need to cast genericData to a List so that I can pass it to another method with signature:

```
public void MapListToField<T>(List<T> genericList)
```

**UPDATE**

Per Eric's response below, I wanted to share an attempt I made that perhaps someone could point out my error. The compiler is stating that I am attempting to use a variable as a Type, which I understand the meaning of, but elementType IS a Type, so I'm unclear how to fix:

```
var elementType = genericData.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
var castedList = genericData as List<elementType>;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Is this close to what you are asking?

Code:

```cs
void Main()
{
    List<string> stringlist = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
    List<int> intlist = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    string notList = "";
    var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Methods), "CastToList", new Type[] { stringlist.GetType(), stringlist.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] }, Expression.Constant(stringlist));
    Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(expression).Compile()();
    expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Methods), "CastToList", new Type[] { intlist.GetType(), intlist.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] }, Expression.Constant(intlist));
    Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(expression).Compile()();
    expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Methods), "CastToList", new Type[] { notList.GetType(), typeof(object) }, Expression.Constant(notList));
    Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(expression).Compile()();
}

public static class Methods
{
    public static void MapListToField<T>(List<T> genericList)
    {
        foreach (var element in genericList)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}, ", element.ToString());
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
    public static bool CastToList<L, T>(L obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(List<T>))
        {
            Console.Write("List contains objects of Type: {0}\n", typeof(T).ToString());
            List<T> genericList = obj as List<T>;
            MapListToField(genericList);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Not list, Type is: {0}\n", typeof(L).ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
List contains objects of Type: System.String
a, b, c, 
List contains objects of Type: System.Int32
1, 2, 3, 
Not list, Type is: System.String
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. I attempted that but once I had the element type I was unable to cast to a list of that type.  I tried something like this:                             var myCastedList = (List<ElementType>) genericData;      It did not like the ElementType I placed in List, complaining that it was variable I was trying to use as a Type

Comment: You can use expressions, they have a lot of flexibility for generic types. You could use Expression.Convert once you have identified the types to cast to the desired type and the execute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654265.aspx

I could try to write a detailed example.

Comment: Do you know the Type of the objects of the list you are expecting to get?

Answer (score -1):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and more specifics about your scenario, it's impossible to know for sure what the best approach would be here. That said…

If the first thing you're going to do is check whether the object is a list and then just pass it to another method that will operate on a list, why not just make two overloads for your method? E.g.:

```
public void MapData<T>(T genericData)
{
    // do stuff with non-list data
}

public void MapData<T>(List<T> genericList)
{
    MapListToField(genericList);
}
```

If there is code that you want to execute for both types, move that to a helper method that both overloads of `MapData<T>()` can call.

Regardless of how you approach this, your current mechanism for checking for the `List<T>` type is way too fragile, and IMHO irretrievably flawed. See [How do I check if a given value is a generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/794198) for some ideas on better ways to do this.