# Copy properties recursively with FastMember

Tags: c#, asp.net, fastmember

I have two objects from this class:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to loop through all the properties of the two object instances with FastMember and copy the properties from `object 1` to `object 2`.

Here's what I got so far (not working!)

```
// Set accessors
var sourceAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(object1);
var targetAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(object2);

foreach (var sourceItem in (IList)sourceAccessor.Target)
{
    var targetItemAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(targetAccessor.Target);
    var sourceItemAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(sourceItem);

    // Overwrite property
    targetItemAccessor[p] = sourceItemAccessor[p];
}
```

this code is obviously not working...any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [shallow copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c-sharp/) with the help of the `TypeAccessor` using something like:

```
var sourceAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(object1);
var targetAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(object2);

var access = TypeAccessor.Create(typeof(A));
var members = access.GetMembers();

foreach (var member in members)
{
    targetAccessor[member.Name] = sourceAccessor[member.Name];
}
```

Have a look at the [FastMember tests](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/blob/master/FastMember.Tests/) for usage examples.

For a deep copy, you could check either the property name or use the [property type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442534/how-to-test-if-type-is-primitive) to determine whether to apply a [deep copy of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007405/how-create-a-new-deep-copy-clone-of-a-listt) or if a shallow copy is sufficient.

Edit: Here is an example for a simplified version that recursively copies properties of type `IList` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794198/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-value-is-a-generic-list) on how to determine which property is a list), assuming the source and target object's lists have the same length:

```
private static void MirrorObject(object object1, object object2)
{
    var sourceAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(object1);
    var targetAccessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(object2);

    var access = TypeAccessor.Create(object1.GetType());
    var members = access.GetMembers();

    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        if (member.Type.IsGenericType && (member.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)))
        {
            var list1 = (IList)sourceAccessor[member.Name];
            var list2 = (IList)targetAccessor[member.Name];
            if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Lists need to be of the same length.");
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
            {
                MirrorObject(list1[i], list2[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            targetAccessor[member.Name] = sourceAccessor[member.Name];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Let's say I want to copy the properties recursively, meaning I want to loop throught the `IList<B>` and `IList<C>` and copy those nested properties?

Comment: You are welcome, I updated the answer to include an example for that use case.

Comment: I'm currently trying to get this work. But on the `member.Type.IsGenericType && (member.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))` part, it also detects a `String` as list...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, e.g.: `var member = "test"; var isList = member.GetType().IsGenericType && (member.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>));` results in `false`.

Comment: @user7217806 i have almost the same code you use, but i get an exception (NotSupportedException), cand you write to me some hint about usage and errors? more detail here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633228/fastmember-getmembers-throw-not-supported-exception

Comment: @Skary Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: @user7217806 yes sorry, i have made a mistake in the code and passed a strange type to fastmember framework (json instance form the newtonsoft JSON framework). I don't know exactily which are difference, but that kind of object is a bit weird, and that is the cause of my problem. So i deleted my question and forgot about this comment. If i use a "normal" object everything work fine, in my scenario only "normal" object have to be managed, so eventually there are no issue.