# Check exception type without considering T C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, .net-core

I have error class:

```
 public class FailureException<TRequest, TResponse> : PartialFailureException<TRequest, TResponse>
    {
        public FailureException(TRequest request, TResponse response, TRequest requestToRetry)
            : base(request, response, requestToRetry) { }
    }
```

And then I have different class to detect errors' types:

```
 public static class ErrorDetector
    {
        public static bool IsFailure(Exception e) =>
            e.GetType() == typeof(FailureException<TRequest, TResponse>));
    }
```

Is it possible to somwehow check type of error without adding `FailureException<TRequest, TResponse>` (just using `FailureException`) so that I wouldn't need to add <TRequest, TResponse> to bunch of other classes?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794198/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-value-is-a-generic-list) answer your question? Just replace `List<>` with `FailureException<,>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can check for the type with an open generic like this:

```cs
e.GetType().IsGenericType && e.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(FailureException<,>)
```

Here we don't specify the type arguments and instead check if the type is the generic type.