.Net Create object that can be passed to method<T> with reflection
Currently I have custom mapper that accepts a TSource and a TDestination;
Edit to clarify: I want to pass var refobj= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(sourcename); to MapToList<TSource, TDestination> as a replacement for TSource.
    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource sourceObject)
    {
       var destinationObject = Activator.CreateInstance<TDestination>();
       if (sourceObject != null)
       {
         foreach (var sourceProperty in typeof(TSource).GetProperties())
         {
             var destinationProperty = typeof(TDestination).GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);                
             destinationProperty?.SetValue(destinationObject, sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceObject));                
         }
     }
     return destinationObject;
}

This is fine until it encounters a List. So I extended the mapper like this
public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource sourceObject)
    {
       var destinationObject = Activator.CreateInstance<TDestination>();
       if (sourceObject != null)
       {
         foreach (var sourceProperty in typeof(TSource).GetProperties())
         {
             var destinationProperty = typeof(TDestination).GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);                
             If (//check for list)
             {
                var sourcename = sourceProperty.ReflectedType?.FullName;
                var refobj= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(sourcename);
                destinationProperty?.SetValue(destinationObject, MapToList<refobj, //destinationRefObj>(listToMap));
             }
             destinationProperty?.SetValue(destinationObject, sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceObject));                
         }
     }
     return destinationObject;
}

Mapping the list.
     private static List<TDestination> MapToList<TSource, TDestination>(List<TSource> source)
 {
     var target = new List<TDestination>(source.Count);
     foreach (var item in source)
     {
        //DOMAP
     }
     return target;
 }

How can I instantiate a class so I can use it to pass to MapToList<TSource, TDestination>? I can't use the reflected object for that because the error is "refobj is a variable but is used like a type". Thanks

Why do you want this in the first place? It's not just that there are multiple such mappers already (eg AutoMapper), but Ahead-Of-Time compilation means you can't use reflection and still get a native binary. The alternative is source generators. There are mappers that use source generators already. Tools like Dapper.AOT also work without reflection

@PanagiotisKanavos Because the entities and DTO objects are in different libraries and i can't set mapperignore values in those libraries. Basically I want more control over the properties to map and I don't want to write a custom mapper for every possibility, thats why i want to use type T

But you are writing a custom mapper for every possibility now. In AutoMapper you specify what to ignore with .Ignore(), you don't need to modify the classes. You can specify global filters too if you can think of a way of detecting the properties you want to ignore

No matter what you do, in the end you'll replicate what AutoMapper does. And one of the most important things is caching the property and type information. In the code you posted most of the code calculates the same things, over and over. You can create a Dictionary<Type,...> instead that maps from source to destination PropertyInfos so you can set the properties directly if the source (or destination) was already encountered

Another possibility is to use FastMember to quickly access and set properties by name. FastMember caches type information internally

Putting aside why you implement custom mapper, when there are many solutions available, you can try following:
    public static class Mapper
{
    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource sourceObject)
    {
        var destinationObject = Activator.CreateInstance<TDestination>();
        if (sourceObject != null)
        {
            foreach (var sourceProperty in typeof(TSource).GetProperties())
            {
                var destinationProperty = typeof(TDestination).GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);

                var sourceValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceObject);
                object mapped;

                if (sourceValue.IsGenericList())
                {
                    mapped = MapToList(sourceProperty.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Single(),
                        destinationProperty.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Single(), sourceValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    mapped = Map(sourceProperty.PropertyType,
                        destinationProperty.PropertyType, sourceValue);
                }

                destinationProperty?.SetValue(destinationObject, mapped);
            }
        }

        return destinationObject;
    }

    private static object Map(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, object value)
    {
        if (destinationType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceType))
        {
            return value;
        }

        var genericMap = typeof(Mapper).GetMethod(nameof(Map), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, destinationType);

        return genericMap.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
    }

    private static object MapToList(Type sourceType, Type destinationType, object value)
    {
        var genericMapToList = typeof(Mapper).GetMethod(nameof(MapToList), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, destinationType);

        return genericMapToList.Invoke(null, new []{value});
    }

    private static List<TDestination> MapToList<TSource, TDestination>(List<TSource> source)
    {
        var target = new List<TDestination>(source.Count);

        var addMethod = target.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var mappedObj = Map(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination), source);

            addMethod.Invoke(target, new object[] { mappedObj });
        }

        return target;
    }

    public static bool IsGenericList(this object o)
    {
        var oType = o.GetType();
        return (oType.IsGenericType && (oType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)));
    }
}

I hope I got it right now, it is a bit more complex problem and this code doesn't have many checks on null etc.
for the generic list check I used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/794257/9855767

I think you misinterpreted my issue. It's the fact that I can't call apToList<TSource, TDestination> because I can't use the object I instantiated with reflection var refobj= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(sourcename); as replacement for TSource

OK, then please edit your post then and show where exactly are you getting the issue

That is noted already in the last part of my post.

do you mean that you are trying to use object created by reflection to fill in generic type parameters?

I want the refobj so the method MapToList<TSource, TDestination> knows what class is T. I don't need the properties, I just need a class to pass as T

unfortunately, you have to do it as I showed in amended answer now :(

I was not exactly what i was looking for but sure is helpful. So ill accept it as the right answer.

I have a feeling what you are looking to do, to pass variable as a T type parameter is actually not possible in C#, anyway, thank you for accepting my answer.
