# Problems with custom deserialization of a list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, serialization

I'm writing a custom deserializer that will deserialize a list by deserializing each of the individual objects in the collection and then putting it together.

Basically my code looks like this:

```
//myField is a FieldInfo that represents the field we want to put the data in
//resultObject is the object we want the data to go into

List<Object> new_objects = new List<Object>();
foreach (String file_name in file_name_list)
{
     Object field_object = MyDeserialization(file_name)
     new_objects.Add(field_object)
}
myField.SetValue(resultObject, new_objects);
```

But this gives an error on the SetValue because (for example) I am trying to put a List(Object) into a List(Int32). Note that this problem only occurs with collections. The following code:

```
Object new_object = MyDeserialization(file_name)
myField.SetValue(resultObject, new_object)
```

works just fine provided that the runtime type of the result of MyDeserialization(file_name) is actually compatible with the type of myField. What is the problem here, and is there a way to make the collection deserialization work? (I've tried replacing the List(Object) declaration with myField.FieldType and that won't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections do not offer covariance... a `List<int>` simply **isn't** a `List<object>` (or v.v.). As such, you need to identify the `T`, for example [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755200/how-do-i-detect-that-an-object-is-a-generic-collection-and-what-types-it-contain) (using the `FieldInfo.FieldType`) - and create the right type of list in the first place.

For convenience, once created it may be simpler to use the non-generic `IList` interface:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
IList list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
list.Add(...); // etc
```

However; I must stress - writing a full (and robust) serializer is a lot of work. Do you have a specific reason? Many of the inbuilt serializers are pretty good - for example [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) - or 3rd party, such as [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), and (if I do say so myself) [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Comment: Actually, I'm not really writing an entire custom serializer. What I'm trying to do is take a very large object and break it up into a whole bunch of smaller objects that can be serialized each in a separate file. For example if one of the fields in the object was a list of 50 records, and each record was a megabyte, if I want to pull out one record I would want to have a way of just deserializing the one record that I want, rather than deserializing the whole object with all 50 records. My serializer would then call a built in serializer to serialize the broken up objects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that .NET can't know that your List is actually a List.  The following code should work:

```
//myField is a FieldInfo that represents the field we want to put the data in
//resultObject is the object we want the data to go into

List<MyType> new_objects = new List<MyType>();
foreach (String file_name in file_name_list)
{
     Object field_object = MyDeserialization(file_name)
     new_objects.Add((MyType)field_object)
}
myField.SetValue(resultObject, new_objects);
```

For Fun Linq Extra Credit (assuming file_name_list is IEnumerable):

```
myField.SetValue(resultObject, file_name_list
           .Select(s => MyDeserialization(s))
           .Cast<MyType>()
           .ToList());
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because MyType is unknown at compile time.