# type of system.Collection <T>

Tags: c#, collections, type-systems

I'm creating a list of `<T>`, but i want to know the type of that T-object. (i'm using reflection in my project, so i don't know the type when i'm creating my code.

So first i have my `List` --> `List<T>` values

Now i want to get all the properties of that T-object (for creating columns in a datagrid)

any help?

Answer (score 11):

You can just use typeof(T) in your class or generic method:

```
void ProcessList<T>(List<T> list) {
    Type typeOfT = typeof(T);
    // Work with type...
}
```

Comment: If the OP is using reflection (question), then there isn't a very good way of calling this method without already knowing the `T` in advance; at least, not until C# 4.0 (you could use it as a dynamic method and let the runtime worry about it).

Answer (score 1):

For a `GetListType` function see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755200/how-do-i-detect-that-an-object-is-a-generic-collection-and-what-types-it-contain/755313#755313). To get the *properties* of the list **for data-binding purposes**, you should really use the component-model (for compatibility) - i.e.

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type);
```

Then look at each `PropertyDescriptor`, using `GetValue` / `Converter` etc. Your list code will generally have to work against the non-generic `IList`; something like:

```
IList list = ...
object obj = list[rowIndex];
// then for any given "prop"
object val = prop.GetValue(obj);
string displayText = prop.Converter.ConvertToString(val);
```

However, if you wanted to be "complete" you'd also need to look at `IListSource` and `ITypedList`

Answer (score 0):

You can take one object from that list and look at its type. Though there is certainly a better way, I think.

Comment: What if not all the collection of the same type?

Comment: @Ahmed - then it isn't a sensible list; actually, looking at the first item in the list is the official fallback approach used when an `IList` isn't also an `ITypedList`, and doesn't have a non-object indexer. So it isn't a *bad* suggestion. But if a `T` *can* be identified from the list itself, it is preferable.

Comment: The question clearly states it's a List<T>, there is no reason why the items in the list would be of different types

Comment: Well, the T might be a supertype of all items in the list, so you get a car for item 1, a bicycle for item 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it as easy as [GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx), and then using reflection for [GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_methods.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 values.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName
```

The above gives you the type object for type 'T'

```
values.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
```

The above gives you the public properties available on 'T',you can pass in the appropriate BindingFlags as you see fit.