# c# - How to deserialize a generic list<T> when I don't know the type of (T)?

Tags: c#, generics, list, ilist, serialization

for auditory reasons I stores the arguments of the business methods serialized into the database using the binaryformatter.

The problem is that when an argument is a generic list I don't find the way to cast the deserialized object because I don't know the type, or If I will know the type I don't know how to cast the object at runtime.

Anybody knows how to cast an object containing a generic list dinamically at runtime?

I need to do this because I need to show the deserialized data in a property grid:

```
object objArg = bformatter.Deserialize(memStr);

//If the type is a clr type (int, string, etc)
if (objArg.GetType().Module.Name == "mscorlib.dll")
{                 
    //If the type is a generic type (List<>, etc) 
    //(I'm only use List for these cases)
    if (objArg.GetType().IsGenericType)
    {
         // here is the problem
         pgArgsIn.SelectedObject = new { Value = objArg};                    

         //In the previous line I need to do something like... 
         //new { Value = (List<objArg.GetYpe()>) objArg};
     }
     else
     {
         pgArgsIn.SelectedObject = new { Value = objArg.ToString() };                    
     }
}
else
{
    //An entity object
    pgArgsIn.SelectedObject = objArg;                
}
```

Comment: "Auditory reasons"? What does this mean in this context?

Comment: For compliance with audit regulations, I'd imagine.

Comment: For info, `BinaryFormatter` is quite brittle if you change your objects. I would recommend a contract-based serializer such as XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, or (for binary) protobuf-net.

Comment: Re your comment; there is a way to do what you ask via custom descriptors; I'll write an example after I've eaten (shortly).

Comment: Added example that doesn't involve finding the T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `BinaryFormatter` you don't **need** to know the type; the metadata is included in the stream (making it bigger, but hey!). However, you can't *cast* unless you know the type. Often in this scenario you have to use common known interfaces (non-generic `IList` etc) and reflection. And lots of it.

I also can't think of a huge requirement to know the type to show in a `PropertyGrid` - since this accepts `object`, just give it what `BinaryFormatter` provides. Is there a specific issue you are seeing there? Again, you might want to check for `IList` (non-generic) - but it isn't worth worrying about `IList<T>`, since this isn't what `PropertyGrid` checks for!

You can of course find the `T` if you *want* ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755200/how-do-i-detect-that-an-object-is-a-generic-collection-and-what-types-it-contain/755313#755313)) - and use `MakeGenericType()` and `Activator.CreateInstance` - not pretty.

---

OK; here's a way using custom descriptors that **doesn't** involve knowing *anything* about the object or the list type; if you **really** want it is possible to expand the list items directly into the properties, so in this example you'd see 2 fake properties ("Fred" and "Wilma") - that is extra work, though ;-p

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Person fred = new Person();
        fred.Name = "Fred";
        fred.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-23);
        Person wilma = new Person();
        wilma.Name = "Wilma";
        wilma.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-20);

        ShowUnknownObject(fred, "Single object");
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(fred);
        list.Add(wilma);
        ShowUnknownObject(list, "List");
    }
    static void ShowUnknownObject(object obj, string caption)
    {
        using(Form form = new Form())
        using (PropertyGrid grid = new PropertyGrid())
        {
            form.Text = caption;
            grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form.Controls.Add(grid);
            grid.SelectedObject = ListWrapper.Wrap(obj);
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(ListWrapperConverter))]
public class ListWrapper
{
    public static object Wrap(object obj)
    {
        IListSource ls = obj as IListSource;
        if (ls != null) obj = ls.GetList(); // list expansions

        IList list = obj as IList;
        return list == null ? obj : new ListWrapper(list);
    }
    private readonly IList list;
    private ListWrapper(IList list)
    {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        this.list = list;
    }
    internal class ListWrapperConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes) {
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
                new PropertyDescriptor[] { new ListWrapperDescriptor(value as ListWrapper) });
        }
    }
    internal class ListWrapperDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor {
        private readonly ListWrapper wrapper;
        internal ListWrapperDescriptor(ListWrapper wrapper) : base("Wrapper", null)
        {
            if (wrapper == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("wrapper");
            this.wrapper = wrapper;
        }
        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return false; }
        public override void ResetValue(object component) {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
        public override bool IsReadOnly {get {return true;}}
        public override void SetValue(object component, object value) {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
        public override object GetValue(object component) {
            return ((ListWrapper)component).list;
        }
        public override Type ComponentType {
            get { return typeof(ListWrapper); }
        }
        public override Type PropertyType {
            get { return wrapper.list.GetType(); }
        }
        public override string DisplayName {
            get {
                IList list = wrapper.list;
                if (list.Count == 0) return "Empty list";

                return "List of " + list.Count
                    + " " + list[0].GetType().Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, I don't know why, but If I set the property grid like this:
pgArgsIn.SelectedObject = new { Value = arg}; //When arg is the deserializaed argument.
I have something like this in the property grid:
Value = [system.collections....], without anything more that brings me a chance to know what the object have inside.
But, if I set the property grid like this:
pgArgsIn.SelectedObject = new { Value = arg as List<Entities.Diagnostico>};                     
I have in the property grid:
Value = (Collection) [...] with a button that show me the list of entities whit her properties.

Comment: Then, I need to cast the deserialized objet at runtime. The activator an other things returns an object, then I dont't have what I need.

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast? PropertyGrid doesn't care about your variable type...

Answer (score 2):

If the serializer you are using does not retain the type - at the least, you must store the type of `T` along with the data, and use that to create the generic list reflectively:

```
//during storage:
Type elementType = myList.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments[0];
string typeNameToSave = elementType.FullName;

//during retrieval
string typeNameFromDatabase = GetTypeNameFromDB();
Type elementType = Type.GetType(typeNameFromDatabase);
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { elementType });
```

Now you have `listType`, which is the exact `List<T>` you used (say, `List<Foo>`). You can pass that type into your deserialization routine.

Comment: Yes! this is a good aproach, I don't have the solution yet. I have the deserialized object, and I have the generic type (List<Entidades.Diagnosticos>). Now, I need to cast the object at runtime, I need to do something like MyTypedObjectArg = objArg as List<Entidades.Diagnosticos>;

Why?.. If I bind the property grid to the object I get: Value = [System.Collection.Generic.List`1], but if I set typed object I have a collection and I can see entities inside and the properties inside the entities, etc.

Comment: `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { elementType });` solved for me