# Can reflection find my collection type at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect that an object is a generic collection, and what types it contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755200/how-do-i-detect-that-an-object-is-a-generic-collection-and-what-types-it-contain)

Hi

I have a generic method that is return a `IEnumerable<T>`, my problem is that I don't now the type of `T` at compile time, I've played around with reflection but can't really get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
Type myType = prop.ReflectedType;
MethodInfo mi = typeof(GenericDataMapper).GetMethod("GetList").MakeGenericMethod(myType);

var Result = mi.Invoke(this, new object[] {"myString"})

private IEnumerable<T> Getlist<T>(string fieldname) where T: class
{
 //The method of course does something....   
Return new List<T>();
}
```

Anybody got a clue?

Comment: If if misunderstood the question and it *isn't* the same thing, add a comment including @Marc (so I get notified) and I can reopen