# C# Instantiate Generic List with Reflected Type Information

Tags: linq, generics, reflection

I am trying to do the following:

1. Given TypeInfo after reflecting on a LINQ-to-SQL object with various EntitySet<> child collections, retrieve the collection
2. Do some operations on the collection

The code below does not compile, obviously - just looking for another way to do this [Note, "Facade" is the L2S object in question).  The things that don't compile are the usages of "itemType" becuase it's a variable, not a Type name, but you get the idea:

```
//itemType is the reflected Type of child object

EntitySet<itemType> list = (EntitySet<itemType>)type.InvokeMember(
                                       info.Name,
                                       BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                                       null,
                                       Facade,
                                       null);


foreach (itemType o in list)
    //do something with o
```

The closest possible dupe I come up with is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class), but there is no ultimate solution.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this works:

```
var list = type.InvokeMember(
                             info.Name,
                             BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                             null,
                             Facade,
                             null);

IEnumerable e = list as IEnumerable;

if (e == null)
    continue;

foreach (object o in e)
    //do stuff with o
```