# how to convert object instance to generic type?

Tags: c#

in a method i have an object like this:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(TargetObject))
```

and i need to pass this object to the other class that accept generic type:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
}
```

how can i use this object as T to Repository class?

Comment: just edited your question with the markup-tool

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with reflection, for example:

```
Type repoType  = typeof(Repository<>).MakeGenericType(yourType);
```

but reflection soon begats *more* reflection - as you'd then need to talk about `repoType` via reflection. There *are* ways of minimising this impact, though:

- non-generic interfaces (the simplest approach)
- calling a generic method *once* via reflection that does all the additional work via regular static generic code

For the first, I might have an `IRepository` interface (non-generic), then it is just:

```
IRepository repo = (IRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(repoType);
repo.SomeNonGenericMethods(args); // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You have define T at design time.

Comment: Sorry, but that is incorrect; you *can* define `T` at runtime (since .NET generics are provided by the runtime, not the compiler), but it isn't trivial and should be restricted only to necessary scenarios.

Comment: Agree with you. But he wanted to pass the created object to the class which is not possible.