# Get object type from collection and passing it to generic class

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created a generic TypeDescriptionProvider. I need to register this provider for a particular type during runtime. The type is extracted from IList, So basically I have this

```
IList
MyTypeProvider<T>
```

and I need to do something like this:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<name>(type), type);
```

I was able to get the T from IList as Type, but I am unable to pass it to MyTypeDescriptionProvider<>.

Thanks,
Goran

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class) what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, something similar to that. Thanks.