# Loading a generic type using Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: c#, generics, late-binding

Referring to the answer by Jon Skeet here: [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266115/592111)

I need to load a Generic type based on the name of the generic type, and the name of the type that is the type parameter for the generic. So from Jon's example I would have:

```
string genName = "MyNamespace.Generic";
string itemName = "System.String";
```

I have the following code that will load a type based on the name of the type and a fully justified assembly name/path. It works fine for "simple types"

```
public Type GetTypeOf(string assemblyPath, string className)
{
    var asmbly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath); //open assembly
    return asmbly.GetType(className, true, true); //throws error, not case sensitive
}
```

I was hoping to use this as follows:

```
//Get the types
var genTyp = GetTypeOf(genPath,genName);
var itemTyp = GetTypeOf(itemPath,itemName);

//Put them together:
var typ = getType.MakeGenericType(itemTyp);
```

This falls over on the first line with a `System.TypeLoadException` stating:

```
Could not load type <TypeName here> from assembly <AssemblyName here>
```

I've tried a number of permutations of creating the generic, included supplying the full class name `MyNamespace.Generic<System.String>`. It works correctly when I specify a non-generic type to load from the same assembly that contains the generic type.

Comment: Can all assemblies be loaded that the genType-assembly depends on?

Comment: Yes. I am able to load a non generic class from genType's assembly with no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, using GetType with generic types is not that readable. You have to use the full qualified type name, even for the generic parameters:. For example, `TestType<object>` reads like this:

```
TestType`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Your sample code does not include the type declarations, so you have to play around with this. You can try this code snippet and take a look what the debugger says:

```
string typeName = typeof(MyNamespace.Generic<>).Name;
string fullTypeName = typeof(MyNamespace.Generic<>).FullName;
```

The results should help you getting the correct type name.

Comment: Thanks very much - that set me on the right path. See my answer for my final fix.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Carsten's answer above, I've adapted my `GetTypeOf` method as follows:

```
    public Type GetGenericTypeOf(string assemblyPath, string genericClass, string itemQualifiedClass)
    {
        string typString = String.Format("{0}`1[[{1}]]",genericClass,itemQualifiedClass)
        var asmbly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath); //open assembly
        return asmbly.GetType(typString, true, true); //throws error, not case sensitive
    }
```

I can then use it as follows:

```
var itemTyp = GetTypeOf(itemPath,itemName);
var genTyp = GetGenericTypeOf(genPath,genName,itemTyp.AssemblyQualifiedName);

//This genTyp is then good to go:
var genInst = Activator.CreateInstance(getTyp);
```

There's no need for `MakeGenericType` as the genType returned bypasses this step.

I've now done a full write up of this, including VB.Net version of the code on my blog [here](http://www.jonegerton.com/dotnet/loading-generic-types-with-assembly-loadfrom).