# Instantiating a generic class where type argument comes from a string

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, instantiation

First I have to reference Jon Skeet's answer to a similar question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/266282/1184296

In his answer he wrote this

```
Type genericClass = typeof(Generic<>);
```

What I don't understand here is how to get Generic<> to show up.

I tried adding `using`s with all the namespaces under `System` but no luck. Nothing shows up in IntelliSense and `Generic<>` stays underlined in red stating "The type or namespace 'Generic' could not be found...".

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the fact that he defined the `Generic` class himself in that same piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code in the Post, John Skeet has created a **custom class**..

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    public Generic()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("T={0}", typeof(T));
    }
}
```

So, you could do the same, you might need John Skeets permission to take that code though? :)

Comment: Give it a different name, and change the Constructor slightly, and nobody will notice...

Comment: Hahaha, I can't believe how obvious thing I missed. That should do it :)