# Type with a generic where the type passed as a generic also has a generic causes an ArgumentException

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create an instance of a type with a generic where the type passed as a generic also has a generic.

The following code is where the problem occurs:

```
internal virtual RouteBase GetRoute(DbContextTypeProvider databaseContextTypeProvider, Type model)
{
    Type catchallRoute = typeof(CatchallRoute<,>);
    catchallRoute.MakeGenericType(new Type[] {
        databaseContextTypeProvider.DbContextType,
        model
    });

    Type routeTypeWrapper = typeof(RouteTypeWrapper<>);
    routeTypeWrapper.MakeGenericType(new Type[] {
        catchallRoute
    });

    RouteTypeProvider routeTypeProvider = (RouteTypeProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(routeTypeWrapper);

    return GetRoute(databaseContextTypeProvider, model, routeTypeProvider);
}
```

I based the code around what can be seen in the following SO question, when I use one type requiring generics in the same way as shown in the accepted answer the instance can be created, but the type requires a type with generics I just can't seem to get this working:

[Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

I can't find any examples on MSDN showing how to create an instance of a type with generics where one of the generics it requires also requires generics.

If I code it so that the types are closed it would look like the following:

```
RouteTypeWrapper<CatchallRoute<SapphireDbContext<SiteTree>,SiteTree>> routeTypeProvider = new RouteTypeWrapper<CatchallRoute<SapphireDbContext<SiteTree>,SiteTree>>();
```

This is effectively what I'm trying to do but using reflection so that arguments can be passed to a method so that an instance can be created and returned.

But when I use reflection I get the following error:

> Cannot create an instance of Sapphire.Cms.Web.Routing.RouteTypeWrapper`1[TRoute] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so how can I correct the code so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MakeGenericType returns a new type.  It does not modify the existing type.  Change your code as below to get the result of MakeGenericType

```
internal virtual RouteBase GetRoute(DbContextTypeProvider databaseContextTypeProvider, Type model)
{
    Type catchallRoute = typeof(CatchallRoute<,>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] {
        databaseContextTypeProvider.DbContextType,
        model
    });

    Type routeTypeWrapper = typeof(RouteTypeWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] {
        catchallRoute
    });

    RouteTypeProvider routeTypeProvider = (RouteTypeProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(routeTypeWrapper);

    return GetRoute(databaseContextTypeProvider, model, routeTypeProvider);
}
```

Comment: `typeof(RouteTypeWrapper<>)` returns the open generic type.  `RouteTypeWrapper<>`.  MakeGenericType returns the closed generic type `RouteTypeWrapper<CatchallRoute<SapphireDbContext<SiteTree>,SiteTree>>`.  The problem in your code was that the result of MakeGenericType was being discarded instead of being put into the variable routeTypeWrapper

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example showing how to do that.

```
class A<T>{}
class B<T>{}
class C<T>{}

...

var atype = typeof(A<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { typeof(int) });
var btype = typeof(B<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { atype });
var ctype = typeof(C<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { btype });

var cinstance = Activator.CreateInstance(ctype);
```