# C# Factory for generic inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, factory, covariant

I apologize for this rather fundamental question, however, I could find no documentation. Perhaps because I do not know the proper terminology.

Class structure:

```
class D{}

abstract class A<T>{}
class B<T> : A<T> {}
class C : B<D> {}
```

I attempt to create a factory method returning C, while the overall return type must be A. Unfortunately this implementation will produce a compiletime error, altough the inheritance structure seems to be consummately covariant.

```
public A<T> FactoryMethod()
{
   return new C();
}
```

More specifically, I am trying to implement a factory, able to produce all three classes based on a input value,  while the generic capability has to be obtained.

```
public A<T> FactoryMethod(int i, Type K)
{
   if(i == 1)
      return new A<K>():

   if(i == 2)
      return new B<K>():

   if(i == 3)
      return new C():
}
```

**Update**

I have to create three objects as follows.

```
A<string> first = FactoryMethod(1, string);
A<int> second = FactoryMethod(2, int);
A<int> third = FactoryMethod(3, int);
```

Comment: What error do you get? What is `T`?

Comment: T is just the usual generic type letter. However D is a concrete class.

Comment: What does the compile error say? You can't just put a `T` there unless it means something in that scope.

Comment: `C` is not generic - it is a `B<D>` and subsequently an `A<D>`.  You cannot return it as an `A<T>` since `T` could be anything.

Comment: @Nex: What if `T` is `string`?

Comment: I updated the question. I do specifiy T, although not in the return type of the method itself. I hoped this would be a dynamics feature of C#.

Comment: That looks like a completely different question to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Comment: Thanks for your reference. This seems almost equal that to my statement of the problem. However I dont see how I can implement this into the factory method, without changing the main method, declaring those three objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C` is a sub class of the bound type `A<D>`.  So the following is valid:

```
public A<D> FactoryMethod()
{
   return new C();
}
```

since we can safely say that `C` is a `A<D>`.  However `C` is not a generic type and cannot be converted to the open type `A<T>` where T is a generic argument since `T` could be any type.

However the following is valid:

```
public A<T> FactoryMethod()
{
   return new B<T>();
}
```

Since `B<T>` is an open generic type as well and any `B<T>` is an `A<T>`.

---

Based on your update, you could write your factory method as:

```
public A<T> FactoryMethod<T>(int i)
{
   if(i == 1)
      return new A<T>():
   if(i == 2)
      return new B<T>():
   if(i == 3) 
      return (A<T>)(object)new C():
      // The cast to object gets rid of compile time checking,
      // but will throw an InvalidCastExceptoin if T is not D
}
```

This is a bit ugly with that weird hack for case 3.  Then you would call it as:

```
A<string> first = FactoryMethod<string>(1);
A<int> second = FactoryMethod<int>(2);
A<int> third = FactoryMethod<int>(3); // InvalidCastException!
```

Comment: Is there anyway else to create a single factory method, able to return all three classes, without the need of specifying T?

Comment: No not directly.  How could you create an `A<>` or `B<>` without specifying `T`.

Comment: I updated the question. I do specifiy T, although not in the return type of the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

In the scope of the class containing `FactoryMethod`, `T` is meaningless. You need to specify the generic parameter of `A` in order to use it as a type.

In this case, because `C` is `B<D>`, and `B<D>` is `A<D>`, then you would use `A<D>` as the return type.

For your second question, if you make the factory method generic I think you can get what you want.

```
public class A<T> {}

public class B<T> : A<T> {}

public class C : B<D> {}

public class D {}

public class Test
{
    public static A<T> FactoryMethod<T>(int i)
    {
       if(i == 1)
          return new A<T>();
       if(i == 2)
          return new B<T>();
       if(i == 3)
          return (A<T>)(object)new C();
       return null;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        A<string> first = FactoryMethod<string>(1);
        A<int> second = FactoryMethod<int>(2);
        A<D> third = FactoryMethod<D>(3);
    }
}
```

Because `C` (`A<D>`) isn't assignable to some `A<T>` (the compiler doesn't know that you'll always pass `3` when `T` is `D`) this isn't type-safe.

Comment: Is there anyway else to create a single factory method, able to return all three classes, without the need of specifying T?

Comment: I've done that in the past by having an interface `IA` so that `A<T> : IA`, and `IA` provides versions of methods that work without a static `T`. But then you start losing type-safety, and it's a tradeoff game.

Comment: Unfortunately most of the classes passed as type to the factory method will be sealed (e.g. Bitmap) and not extendable.

Comment: That's not what I meant: `A<T>` is your abstract type, and `IA` is an interface that `A<T>` implements. `IA` could return `object`s instead of `T`s (or something) and you can deal with their type later.

Answer (score 1):

Given this:

```
class D{}

class A<T>{}
class B<T> : A<T> {}
class C : B<D> {}
enum openT
{
    level1, level2
}
```

I think that you might be looking for this:

```
public A<T> FactoryMethod<T>(openT i)
{
   if(i == openT.level1)
      return new A<T>():

   if(i == openT.level2)
      return new B<T>():

}

public A<D> FactoryMethod()
{
    return new C():
}

public static void Main()
{
    A<string> first = OpenFactoryMethod<string>(1);
    A<int> second = OpenFactoryMethod<int>(2);
    A<D> third = FactoryMethod();
}
```

Note that A cannot be abstract since you are trying to construct it.

I'm failing to see what you are really trying to accomplish here though, since C is a closed type, and therefore your factory method will never make sense for it.

**UPDATED**

The following might be closer to what you are looking for:

```
public TAofT FactoryMethod<TAofT, T>() where TAofT : A<T>, new()
{
    return new TAofT():
}

public static void Main()
{
    A<string> first = FactoryMethod<A<string>, string>();
    A<int> second = FactoryMethod<B<int>, int>();
    A<D> third = FactoryMethod<C, D>();
}
```

But the factory method then seems redundant, since you could just do:

```
public static void Main()
{
    A<string> first = new A<string>();
    A<int> second = new B<int>();
    A<D> third = new C();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Unless what you really want is this:

```
public abstract class AEnum<T, T3> where T3 : B<T>, new()
{
    private static Func<A<T>> factoryMethod;

    public static readonly Level1 = new AEnum<T>(()=>new A<T>());
    public static readonly Level2 = new AEnum<T>(()=>new B<T>());
    public static readonly Level3 = new AEnum<T>(()=>new T3());

    protected AEnum(Func<A<T>> factoryMethod) { this.factoryMethod = factoryMethod; }

    public A<T> New() { return this.factoryMethod(); }
}
```

used like this:

```
public class DEnum : AEnum<D, C>
{
}
```

with:

```
public static void Main()
{
    A<D> first = DEnum.Level1.New();
    A<D> second = DEnum.Level2.New();
    A<D> third = DEnum.Level3.New();
}
```

But then you could not mix enum types, since the above is type constrained to `D`.

**Or** you could do:

```
public class OpenAEnum<T, T3> : AEnum<T, T3> where T3 : B<T3>
{
}

public class CInt : B<int> {}
public class Cstring : B<string> {}
```

with:

```
public static void Main()
{
    A<string> first = OpenAEnum<string, CString>.Level1.New();
    A<int> second = OpenAEnum<int, CInt>.Level2.New();
    A<D> third = OpenAEnum<D, C>.Level3.New();
}
```

What is it that you are trying to do?