# Using C# convert a column of a datatable to a list of the same type

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net

I would like to create a method to convert a column of a datatable to a list having the same type as the column of the datatable without knowing the type in advance. Thus far I am only able to create a generic list.

I would prefer not to create a generic list but instead create a list with the same type as the datatable column and allow for nulls.

Ideally, this method would work with nulls or DBNull.Value in the datatable column.

```
public static List<dynamic> ColumnToList(this DataTable dtWhole, string colToSlice)
{
    List<dynamic> retList = new List<dynamic>();
    Type X = dtWhole.Columns[colToSlice].DataType;
    for (int i = 0; i < dtWhole.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((dtWhole.Rows[i][colToSlice] == DBNull.Value) 
            || (dtWhole.Rows[i][colToSlice] == null))
        {
            retList.Add(null);
        }
        else
        {
            retList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(dtWhole.Rows[i][colToSlice], X));
        }

    }   
    return retList;
}
```

Comment: And now? What is the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Comment: The question is how does one create a method that creates a typed list from a specific column of a datatable without knowing in advance the type of the column. @RezaAghaei.

Comment: If the column in the datatable is a column of integers then the method should output a List<int?>