# Generic class to return particular set of data depending on type

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface

```
public interface IFetchData<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems();
}
```

Two classes inherit from this interface `FetchFromDatabase` and `FetchFromCollection`. The purpose is to switch between classes injected to another class that let's say present them on screen etc. Depending on type used, I would like to fetch data from a particular collection depending on a type. It was not a problem to implement this functionality in `FetchFromDatabase` because `DbContext` has method `DbContext.Set<>()` which returns particular table.

I am looking for the way to do it using collections. In `FetchFromCollection` in line 23: `return modules.Set();`, compiler reports error:

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MainProgram.Models.Module>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't know how to convert `Module` class to generic type `TEntity`. I tried to use intermediate class `ModelBase` and inherit to concrete definitions but then I would have to use another level of injection and decide by myself to which concrete class to use.

I found something here [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class) which is the way of using reflection. I am still confused how to achieve this. Any suggestions please?

FetchFromDatabase

```
public class FetchFromDatabase<TEntity> : IFetchData<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly MainDBContextBase context;

    public FetchFromDatabase(MainDBContextBase context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("DB context");
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems()
    {
        return context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

FetchFromCollection

```
public class FetchFromCollection<TEntity> : IFetchData<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly InitializeComponents components;
    private ModelModules modules;
    private ModelSpecializations specializations;
    private ModelTeachers techers;
    private ModelStudents students;

    public FetchFromCollection(InitializeComponents components)
    {
        if (components == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Context");
        this.components = components;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetItems()
    {
        if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Module))
        {
            if (modules == null)
                modules = new ModelModules(components);
            return modules.Set();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are the classes which implement the interface generic? Why don't you write: public class FetchFromCollection : IFetchData<Module>.

Comment: But if I do it this way, `FetchFromCollection` will return only one collection. I would like to return different collection depending on the type, something similar to what `DbContext<> Set<>.()` does

Comment: Then why do you write "if (typeof(TEntity) == typeof(Module))"? Perhaps you can elaborate on ModelModules?

Comment: `DbContext` returns collection in database depedning on type, you provide the type and get data from particular table. I have to use generic because I want to switch between database and collection in another class. Classes are injected via interface. So I created generic interface to hadnle both `DbContext` and collections. ModelModules is something are tried inbetween but ended up with another level of injection. `if ...` is so far the only way I came across.

Comment: I am not saying how I have done it is the best way. In the end, I am learning all this. If you have anything you can suggest then please I am open to any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try explicit cast?

```
return (IEnumerable<TEntity>)modules.Set();
```

Comment: For some reason, I did give me error when I tried to do it before. That's why I made this question. When I re-build the solution the error disappeared. Thanks. Just a question is there any better way of doing this? I don't think what I created is the prettiest way :p