# C# Reflection, create instance from text

Tags: c#, reflection, types

**EDIT:** All things working now, I was getting the Type.GetType() wrong.

The correct answer is proven correct with 1 change:

```
.GetMethod("Deserialize", new[] { typeof(string) })
```

---

I want to create different types based on some text. I have tried the following without success:

JSON input:

```
[{"Type":"Book","Details":{"Name":"Book1","Chapter":"1","StartPage":"5","EndPage":"23"}},{"Type":"WebPage","Details":{"Name":"Page1","Url":"sometesturl.com","PageTypeIDs":"1"}}]
```

Since I do not want to change code every time a new type is added I tought reflection might be the solution.

```
List<Source> sources = new List<Source>();

dynamic[] items = jsSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(validjson);
foreach (var item in items)
        {
            string type = item["Type"];

            string serialized = jsSerializer.Serialize(item["Details"]);

            Type t = Type.GetType(type);
            var instance = createInstanceFromJSON(t, serialized);

            sources.Add(instance);
        }
```

Will give the following error: ***'Cannot be converted from 'System.Type' to 'ProjectManager.Sources''*** note that the type is in a seperate DLL called ProjectManager.

Here's the method:

```
private T createInstanceFromJSON<T>(T type, string json) where T : class
    {
        ConstructorInfo construtorInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
        ParameterInfo contructor = construtorInfo.GetParameters()[0];
        object defaultValue = contructor.DefaultValue;

        var item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), defaultValue);

        item = jsSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);

        return item;

    }
```

Comment: You're passing an instance of System.Type into  createInstanceFromJSON.  Within createInstanceFromJSON, T is now System.Type.  Then you're calling `typeof(T)` on this object, which returns... System.Type.  This isn't what you want.  `T type` should be `Type type`, and you should pass `typeof(ProjectManager.Sources)` into createInstanceFromJSON.  Then, don't do `typeof(T).GetConstructor`, just do `type.GetConstructor`.  Your code is a bit of a mess, and you should debug it step by step to see what's going on.

Comment: In addition to that, you could remove the reflection completely since you return the result of the `jsSerializer.Deserializer` call (in your `createInstanceFromJSON`) which doesn't depend on the things you do with reflection.

Comment: You cannot pass a Type as a generic and expect to return something other than a type. Check out this for more information about using reflection with generics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you wanted to do is

```
// no need to make this method generic
private Source createInstanceFromJSON(Type type, string json)
{
    // use reflection to get the method for type "type"
    var deserializeMethod =
        jsSerializer.GetType()
                    .GetMethod("Deserialize")
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type });

    // invoke the method on the jsSerializer object
    var item = (Source)deserializeMethod.Invoke(jsSerializer, new[] { json });

    return item;
}
```

Then you can use

```
string type = item["Type"];
string serialized = jsSerializer.Serialize(item["Details"]);

Type t = Type.GetType(type);
Source instance = createInstanceFromJSON(t, serialized);

sources.Add(instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generic parameter `T` will always have the type `System.Type` as it is the type describing your Object that you pass as the method parameter.

You have to construct your constructor method differently as you have to call that one already by a reflective call if you want to use the Generic `<T>` call. Otherwise the compiler will have no idea of what to invoke since T will only be determined `T` at runtime.

OR

You can salvage your current code using reflection to call that method with the correct type. Remove the first parameter of the method...

```
private T createInstanceFromJSON<T>(string json) where T : class
{
    ConstructorInfo construtorInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
    ParameterInfo contructor = construtorInfo.GetParameters()[0];
    object defaultValue = contructor.DefaultValue;

    var item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), defaultValue);

    item = jsSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);

    return item;

}
```

and then use `MethodInfo` to call the method with your generic type:

```
Type t= Type.GetType(type);
MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("createInstanceFromJSON", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
var instance = method.Invoke(this, serialized);
```

Although I do not know if that is really helpful to you, it should at least work.