# Using reflection to supply generic type to a method?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm not sure this is possible with reflection, but thought I'd ask.  I'm using a data access class that relies on generics to determine the 'row type' which we're querying against.

A couple of examples will show what I mean better than anything:

```
int count1 = connection.Count<PersonRow>("i.FirstName ='David'");
int count2 = connection.Count<CarRow>("i.CarModel = 'Chevrolet'");
```

Both `PersonRow` and `CarRow` inherit from an abstract `Row` class.

As you can see, the type of `Row` we're querying against dictates what our query structure will be.

I'd like to store a bunch of these queries as strings in a database or configuration file, rather than hard-code them.  That way we can let users write their own queries as they like, and the code loops over the configuration and runs them one at a time.

Trouble is, I don't know if I can pull this off given the Generic requirement above?

I'd love for the configuration to store the kind of row (as a string) along with a string for the query itself, then use reflection to supply the row class in the `Count<>` method.

I've been playing with `Type.GetType()` and `Type.MakeGenericType()` to see if 
I can finagle something, but am having no luck.

While looking around, I've seen several articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class) that show how to instantiate a generic class using reflection, but I need the class type, not an actual object.  Is there a way to pull this off?

Comment: Please clarify what 'connection' is.  Is it a List<Row>?
Also, can I assume FirstName is a member of PersonRow and CarModel is a member of CarRow and Row has not members relevant to this question?

Comment: @markshancock your assumptions are correct regarding FirstName and CarModel.  'connection' is a database access class mentioned at the start, considerably more complicated than a List of Rows.

Comment: Is connection derived off of IEnumerable?

Comment: If it is derived off IEnumerable, consider using Linq.