# Create Object From Generic Class using class Name C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have a Generic class of T where T is a class 
i want to create an object from this Generic Class but I have Class name in string 
this my code

```
public class GenericClass<T>:IGeneric<T> where T : class
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Get
    {
        //Whatever The Logic Is
    }
}
```

Comment: What *is* your string? It surely must be something like `"GenericClass<MyType>"`, is it? So please show the exact signature of your method you want. Be aware that as you provide `T` at runtime there´s no way to return an `IEnumerable<T>` from your method. You can only return `IEnumerable<object>`. Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class/266282

Comment: I can create object easily if i know the class like `var g= new GenericClass<Employee>()` but I get The class Name at the run time in a  string format, like `string c="Employee"`

Comment: Then the duplicate is *exactly* what you should do.