# C# Construct a default object for a Tuple by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, tuples

In my C# application, I have the need to create an instance of a Tuple. But here's the catch - I don't know the Tuple type in advance, only at runtime. If I have methods that can create instances of any types likely to be in the Tuple, then is there a way to use reflection to create such a Tuple instance? For example, I'm thinking along these lines, but I can't get it to work:

```
if (type typeof(Tuple))
{
    FieldInfo[] fieldInfoArray = type.GetFields();
    object[] = CreateArrayOfObjectsFromFieldInfoArray(fieldInfoArray);
    return new Tuple(objectArray);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you´re looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class

Comment: how about Tuple<object, object>

Comment: I guess u can also use Tuple.Create like Tuple.Create("cat", 2, true);

Comment: Wow - three comments already! I don't know the length or types or the Tuple members, so can't use suggestions 2 or 3. I read through the referenced question, but attempting to use something like defaultObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type, true); throws an exception No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Tuple.Create` method to much more easily construct the object than using a constructor (both when writing the code statically, and also using reflection).  You can use the `FieldInfo` objects to figure out which overload of `Create` to call, and then pass in the values that you have when invoking that overload.

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfoArray = type.GetFields();
object[] values = CreateArrayOfObjectsFromFieldInfoArray(fieldInfoArray);
Type[] typeArguments = fieldInfoArray.Select(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.FieldType).ToArray();
return typeof(Tuple).GetMethods()
    .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == "Create" && method.GetParameters().Length == typeArguments.Length)
    ?.MakeGenericMethod(typeArguments)
    ?.Invoke(null, values);
```

Comment: This looks good -in order to try it, I need to test if a type is a Tuple. I thought the following would work, but it does not: typeof(Tuple).IsAssignableFrom(type); What would be the right way to test for the Tuple type?

Comment: @user304582 If the type is *already* a `Tuple` you don't need to create a new one, you already have one.  Regardless, that's an entirely different question from the one that you asked.

Comment: Great, thanks - I'll do some googling on the test for a Tuple, and post a separate question if need be. In the meantime, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: This code seems to work to check for a Tuple type: Type genericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<>)) || 
        genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<,>)) || 
        genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<,,>)) || 
        genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<,,,>)) || 
        genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<,,,,>)) ||
        genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<,,,,,>)) ||
        genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,>)) ||
        genericType.Equals(typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,,>)))
    {
        return true;
    }

Comment: Unfortunately, I hit a problem with the call: type.GetFields(). Instead of returning an expected FieldInfo array of length 2, I get an array of length 0 Here is the type definition for the Tuple: type = {Name = "Tuple`2" FullName = "System.Tuple`2[[System.String, ...],[System.Byte[], ...]]"} I tried various BindingFlags combinations without success as well. Any ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem of getting the types using this call: Type[] typeArray = type.GetGenericArguments(); This returns an array of length two, first a String and the second a byte array as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the code in the first answer to work, but after some trial and error, I got the following to work:

```
Type[] typeArray = type.GetGenericArguments();
object[] values = CreateArrayOfObjectsFromFieldInfoArray(typeArray);
defaultObject = type.GetConstructor(typeArray)?.Invoke(values);
```