# Initialize generic class by string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string "MyClass". Is there any way to initialize a generic object by string?

```
public void LoadToCache<T>(string key) where T : class, new()
{
  //string key is a class name like "MyClass"
    using (var bl = new BusinessLayer<key>())
    {
       bl.GetAll();
    }
} 
//---------------------------------------------------------------
public class BusinessLayer<T> where T : class
{
  ..
  ..
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyClass
{
  ..
  ..
}
```

Comment: Try to use [MakeGenericType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype)

Comment: You can do that using reflection like Aleks suggested, but you may not be able to use the instance as you expect. Since the compiler won't know the type of the instance at runtime, you will not be able to call `GetAll()` (except again via reflection or by using `dynamic`). It seems you have a design flaw and an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. If you add context about _what you are actually trying to achieve_ someone may show you a better overall approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Comment: @Dmitry Pavliv in that is it possible to use bl.GetAll()?

Comment: @RenéVogt. I have string list which contains class name. And I also have a generic type repository class. My task is read string from the list and call repository method.

Answer (score -1):

You could get the types from your assembly by reflection and create a instance using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

I Hope this helps:

My class:

```
public class Car
{

}
```

The method:

```
string myClass = "Car";
var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().ToList();
var myType = types.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IsClass && i.Name == myClass);
var instance  = Activator.CreateInstance((Type) myType);

Console.Write(instance.ToString());
```