# How to assign a List's data type from a model in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, model

I'm doing a ASP .NET MVC project, in my code I want to assign a List's data type from a Model using the GetType function but I got errors, is this possible?

```
Type fileType = Type.GetType("MyProject.Models.User");
List<fileType> listUser = null;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the type of `List<>`, make it a generic type wrapping your reflected type, and invoke methods on it.

```
var type = typeof(string);

var listType = typeof(List<>);
var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(type);

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);

constructedListType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, new[] { "1" });
constructedListType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, new[] { "2" });
constructedListType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, new[] { "3" });

Console.WriteLine($"instance has {((List<string>)instance).Count} item(s)");
Console.WriteLine($"instance[0] is {((List<string>)instance)[0]}");

// Output
// instance has 3 item(s)
// instance[0] is 1
```

Comment: Great, work it!. Now how can I assign the data type into the follow function: csvContext.Read<Models.User>(streamReader, csvFileDescription).ToList(); to: csvContext.Read<type>(streamReader, csvFileDescription).ToList();

Comment: Two answers already exist with the same code and the question was marked as possible duplicate. Why add one more?