# How optimize many conditions with casting?

Tags: c#, optimization

Please is possible optimise this code, with dictionary? Or otherwise.

```
if (node.Type.Equals(NodeType.CONTAINER))
{
    DataUtils.ContainerToData((INode<ContainerValue>) node, data);
}
else if (node.Type.Equals(NodeType.TEXT))
{
    DataUtils.TextToData((INode<TextValue>) node, data);
}
```

I have 15 this conditions.

I thought that dictionary will work, but how make casting? `(INode<pair.Value>) node`. I looking somethink solution like is this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
dictionary.Add(NodeType.CONTAINER, tyeof(ContainerValue));
dictionary.Add(NodeType.TEXT, tyeof(TextValue));

foreach (var pair in dictionary)
{
    if(node.Type.Equals(pair.Key))
    {
        // wrong
        DataUtils.ContainerToData((INode<pair.Value>) node, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: "but how make retyping?" - Sorry, didn't understand you.

Comment: what is the type of `data` ?

Comment: retype = casting :)

Comment: Your first snippet contains `DataUtils.TextToData`, is that correct?

Comment: details for data or node are not importat. It is are objects

Comment: ``DataUtils.TextToData`` is correct but text is not string. is it not important

Comment: @Abedron We need some definition of `Node`, `INode`, `ContainerValue` and `TextValue` to know the relation. At least the structure. And is `NodeType.CONTAINER` a struct of an actual `Type` or is it an override of `Type` in the class. It's confusing.

Comment: I think you want something like [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266115/215552) but the question is quite unclear.

Comment: Considering the solutions in that question use reflection, you might be better off with your original solution...

Comment: Are you actually bothered about performance? (Your question asks about optimization.) I'd be surprised if this was actually a bottleneck.

Comment: But why can't you just use single method in the `DataUtil` like `ToData` which would have multiple overloads for all types you need to handle and then use some generic to cast ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use a switch stament:

[csharp-pattern-matching-7-0](http://%20https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/11/csharp-pattern-matching-7-0/)

```
                switch (node)
                {
                    case INode<ContainerValue> containerValue:
                        DataUtils.ContainerToData(containerValue, data);
                        break;
                    case INode<TextValue> textValue:
                        DataUtils.ContainerToData(textValue, data);
                        break;

                }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, but I need as first check ``node.Type.Equals`` and rewrite conditions to ``foreach`` cycle.