# Create IEnumerable<T> and add items to it

Tags: c#

I have a given `type` and a Comma Separated Values `string`:

```
Type type = service.getType();

String csv = "1,2,3";
```

I need to convert the `csv` string to an `IEnumerable` of `type`.

I know that `type` will be numeric, e.g., `int`, `short`, `long`, etc.

I am able to spit the `csv` and convert each one to given `type` ..

```
String[] inputs = csv.Split(',');

TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(modelType);

if (converter != null) {

  foreach (String input in inputs) {
    if (converter.CanConvertTo(type)) {
      var number = converter.ConvertFromString(input);
      // Add number to an IEnumerable of numbers
    }

  }

}
```

I am not able to create an `IEnumerable` of `type` and add numbers to it.

How can I do this?

Comment: `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable` , use it and call it's `Add` method to add each value in it

Comment: Yes, but how to create a List of T where T is type? And add each number to it.

Comment: you need to use reflection

Comment: i have posted piece of code to demonstrate how you can achieve that.

Comment: You should avoid the problem all together and just use a CSV Parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have the type at run-time, so you will need to use reflection to create an object of type `List<T>` where T is the instance of class `Type` which you are getting from service. The following code will create an instance of type `List<T>` while `T` is not type at compile time but instead it is resolved at run-time. Following is the code to create that:

```
var listTypeInstance = typeof(List<>);
var instanceList = listTypeInstance.MakeGenericType(type);

var numbers = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(instanceList);
```

Now you can call the `Add` method and add each number in it like:

```
var number = converter.ConvertFromString(input);
numbers.Add(number);
```

Adjusted in your code will look something like following:

```
var listTypeInstance = typeof(List<>);
var instanceList = listTypeInstance.MakeGenericType(type);

var numbers = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(instanceList);

foreach (String input in inputs) {
    if (converter.CanConvertTo(type)) {
      var number = converter.ConvertFromString(input);
      // Add number to an IEnumerable of numbers
      numbers.Add(number);
    }
```

Comment: That was what I did before but in this line `var numbers = Activator.CreateInstance(instanceList);` numbers is Object. And number.Add method is not recognised.

Comment: cast it to `IList`

Comment: like: `var numbers = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(instanceList);`

Comment: check this good explained answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/266282/1875256

Answer (score 2):

Use `dynamic` to skip the compile-time error.

```
var runtimeTypes = new List<Type>
{
    typeof(int),
    typeof(long)
};
foreach (var item in runtimeTypes)
{
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(item);
    dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    list.Add(1); // Call Add() on dynamic works!
    Console.WriteLine(list[0]);
}
```