# Get a class type using a string

Tags: c#, class

Here is a string defining the class name.

```
string classname = "MyClass";
```

Here is the class.

```
class MyClass{ 
}
```

I want to use string for generictype.

ex)`List<Myclass>`

What should I do?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
List <Type.GetType($"ConsoleApp1.{classname}")> classlist;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use a non-specific class in your generic list?  It sort of defeats the object of generics.   You could just use `List<object>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't just do that but you can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to do this. An example would look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string className = "StackOverflow.MyClass";

            // Generating the generic list
            var type = Type.GetType(className);
            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type }); 
            var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

            // Adding a value to the list
            var value = new MyClass();
            list.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(list, new object[] { value });

            // Fetch a value of the list
            var myClass = (MyClass)list.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item").Invoke(list, new object[] { 0 });

            // Invoke methods of MyClass-instance
            Console.WriteLine(myClass.ToString());                                        

            // Keep console open
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As [madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394572/madreflection) has mentioned in the comments above, you can find additonal examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class).

To clear things up a bit, you could use a `list` of `object` instead of creating the list via `reflection`.

```
string className = "StackOverflow.MyClass";
var type = Type.GetType(className);

// Generating the list of objects
var list = new List<object>();

// Adding a value to the list
var value = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
list.Add(value);

// Fetch a value from the list
var myClass = (MyClass)list[0];

// Invoke methods of MyClass-instance
Console.WriteLine(myClass.ToString());
```