# Global alias types c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to do like that in c#...

```
Type myDict = Dictionary<string, object>;
Type myDictList = List<myDict>;
```

It's kind of possible in typescript, but after looking hard and long, didn't find whether it's possible at all.

Comment: `Type myDict = typeof(Dictionary<string, object>)`, and then Possible duplicate of [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Comment: This works, thanks, @GSerg Can't understand how i didn't think of that myself :D

Comment: And..., If you have an object of a particular Type you can get the type information by calling GetType: `Type someType = objectOfSomeType.GetType();`

Comment: well... Actually what i looked for is called global type aliases(e.g. using MyTypeName = Dictionary<string, object>;).

these are valid only for current file and can't be exported unfortunately atm.

I wanted that to shorten some names like List<Dictionary<string, MyCustomType>>, which i use a lot.

Comment: You can always inherit from that ype.

Comment: Just tried it. If i inherit from it, type casts won't work. Intellisense tells everything's ok, but it fails at runtime. Type casts are for unboxing(i'm writing json (de)serialization solution for some ScriptableObject unity entites. Unfortunately, can't be automated using json frameworks/packages, and writing such code in static type language is a pain :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible by adding file, for example `GlobalUsings.cs` with the following declaration:

```cs
global using MyDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well seems like what i was looking for were [actually](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1170) global type aliases.
E.g. `using MyType = List<Dictionary<string, MyOtherCustomType>>;` to shorten the type name for more readable code.

Unfortunately, they're valid only per-file.

Comment: use `gobal using` instead `using` to make it global alias, see the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77210848/475727