# C# Replace <T> dynamically

Tags: c#, .net-core

How can I replace `<T>` from the name of the class dynamically? I would like to be able to replace `T` using string of the class name.

I tried

```
Type type = Type.GetType(classname);
configuration.GetSection($"ProjectConfig").Get <type> ()
```

I get a syntax error for the second line in for `type`:

> Type is a variable but used as a type

Comment: You can work with generic classes and methods using Reflection, but you can't do what you are showing

Comment: Could you describe what you are attempting to achieve here ? Dynamically instantiate a generic class ? you could do so using reflection

Comment: `.Get(type)` exists, but you should explain the context. Right now this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: added more explanation in the post. I am would like to replace T using string of the classname

Comment: What type is `configuration` variable? Why same section would contain different types? If configurations are JSON, you can retrieve configurations as a string and deserialize it to the type by type name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that.

.Net generics are not dynamic, they are resolved at compile time. E.g. supposed you use `List<string>` and `List<int>`, at compile time, the compiler will create 2 new classes `` List`string `` and `` List`int ``.

Generics are meant to provide strong typing at compile time.

If you're asking how to bind the content of configuration to your specific object, You can instantiate the object dynamically using reflection and then use `configuration.Bind(anyObject)` to populate it.

Comment: .Net generics *are* dynamic. `typeof(List<>)..MakeGenericType(type)`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - No, they are not. Your sample code is still compiled and strongly-typed.

Comment: Types are loaded into memory dynamically by the runtime. `.MakeGenericType(type)` creates a new "instance" of a generic type in memory, with its own static variables. Want a more complex example? `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Select(t => typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t))` (with exception handling). None of those `List<X>` appear anywhere in my source code, none were discovered by the compiler, yet they are all now types loaded into memory, which I can create instances of using reflection.