# how to pass classtype dymanically to generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have this kind of requirement as there are around 100+ model classes.

I have repository pattern implemented for database operations:

```
public class interface IRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>where TEntity : class
```

It has a method `Task Add(TEntity entity);`

Under normal circumstances, I would just do this if I want to add UserClass model to DB

```
public class UserClass { string Name }
    
UserClass userClassObj = new UserClass { Name = "John" }

await Repository <UserClass>.Add(userClassObj);
```

However, my requirement is to pass pass class type dynamically based on condition as i have around 100+ models.

```
if (condition == "1")
   classtype = USerClass
else if (condition == "2")
   classtype = DepartmentClass
else if (condition == "3")
   classtype = CategoryClass
```

and then pass classtype to the repository

```
await Repository <classtype>.Add(object of (classtype ));
```

Is this doable? Any working example will be highly appreciated. Could not find straight forward implementation so far.

Comment: Not without reflection - just do `.Add` separately - why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, can you please provide example of achieving this by reflection?

i want to do this because i don't want to create 100+ implementation just to perform common CRUD operation.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/266282/4800344

Answer (score 1):

You might need to extend your class definition like this,

```
public class interface IRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>where TEntity : class, new()
```

`new()` enables creating new object based on passed type.

then you can call it like this,

```
if (condition == "1")
   await Repository<USerClass>.Add(object);
else if (condition == "2")
   await Repository<DepartmentClass>.Add(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Reflection
may add an extra add helper method to (maybe also to your IRepositoryType not sure if `this<T>` work)

```
 public static async Task Add<T>(T objectToAdd) where T : TEntity
 {
    await Repository<T>.Add(objectToAdd)
 }
```

if you have the type argument and a parameter that needs the type you dont have to specify it any more and it will chosoe usually the right type argument with the given parameter type. E.g.

```
var userObject = new UserObject();
Repository.Add(userObject);
```

will automaticly detect that it is the userbject the type to be add

another possibility would be to use a Dictionary<Type,yourDBsetType>() and match it by the type key

Comment: This doesn't work because the OP has a reference to his type that is not for the type itself. It'd be like `object instance = new UserObject();` If you call `Respository.Add(instance)` the inferred type would be `object`.