# Create generic collection from `Type`

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a generic collection for example `List<T>` from `Type`.

Something like this:

```
static List<T> Crete() => new List<T>();
```

But when I have the `Type` and not generic call

```
static List<itemType> Create(Type itemType)
```

To clarify, I don't want to return `object`, `dynamic`, or any `interface` or `List<>` of those. I want the real type that i have in `itemType`, I am not sure its possible at all.

for example `itemType` is `int` → it will return `List<int>`, same for reference types.

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). While it is possible to create such a list, `Create` cannot have a return type of `List<itemType>`. What are you planning on doing with the return value of `Create`?

Comment: I want to create `Dictionary<numeric type, string>` from `enum` and I want to have the real underlying type

I have this, yet the declaration of the variable type is `Dictionary<object, string>`, this is what I want to change

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include more details. How is the dictionary related to the enum? Show the enum declaration and the desired dictionary that you want to create, and most importantly as this is an XY problem, explain what you are going to do with such a dictionary.

Comment: How do you use the dictionary? Please show some examples.

Comment: Generally I want just for debug purposes more that real needs, and also I want to understand if its possible as ability because of interest, not just as a practical question.

Comment: I don't see how this is duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I'm not sure if this is what you wanted to see

You need to use Generic Type

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Create(new int()));//System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
    Console.WriteLine(Create(new Shop()));//System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Testspace.Shop]
}
private static List<T> Create<T>(T type)
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```