# Get class from Type with Reflection and call a generic constructor with Type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, dapper

I am working with Dapper and I want to iterate through my model classes and set type mapping for any class having a field decorated with a `ColumnAttribute`.

```
public class ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<T> : FallbackTypeMapper
{
    public static readonly string ColumnAttributeName = "ColumnAttribute";

    public ColumnAttributeTypeMapper()
        : base(new SqlMapper.ITypeMap[]
        {
            new CustomPropertyTypeMap(typeof (T), SelectProperty),
            new DefaultTypeMap(typeof (T))
        })
    {
    }
    // implementation of SelectProperty and so on...
    // If required, full implementation is on https://gist.github.com/senjacob/8539127
}
```

In my model class library, I'm iterating through all possible types; now I need to call the generic `ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<T>` constructor with the class of the type.

```
using System.Web;
using Dapper;

[assembly : PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Model.Initiator), "RegisterTypeMaps")]

namespace Model
{
    class Initiator
    {
        public static void RegisterTypeMaps()
        {
            var mappedTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (Initiator)).GetTypes().Where(
                f =>
                f.GetProperties().Any(
                    p =>
                    p.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(
                        a => a.GetType().Name == ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<dynamic>.ColumnAttributeName)));

            // I want to skip registering each class manually :P
            // SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(Model1), new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<Model1>());
            // SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(Model2), new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<Model2>());

            foreach (var mappedType in mappedTypes)
            {
                SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(mappedType, new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<mappedType>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I pass the class from type instead of type 'mappedType' to `new ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<classof(mappedType)?>()`

I found [this as a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535), but I need to call the generic constructor instead of a generic method with the `Type`.

If it can not be done, could you please explain the reason?

### Answer

This is how the mapping worked as suggested by Tom.

```
var mapper = typeof(ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<>);
foreach (var mappedType in mappedTypes)
{
    var genericType = mapper.MakeGenericType(new[] { mappedType });
    SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(mappedType, Activator.CreateInstance(genericType) as SqlMapper.ITypeMap);
}
```

Comment: [C sharp dynamic generic type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078914/c-sharp-dynamic-generic-type) | [Dynamically create a generic type in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370/dynamically-create-a-generic-type-for-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need the method `Type.MakeGenericType`; usage is as follows:

```
var columnType = typeof(ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<>);
var genericColumn = columnType.MakeGenericType(new[] {typeof(mappedType)});
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericColumn);
```

I'm writing this without intellisense and only having skimmed your code, so please let me know whether I've made any mistakes and I'll correct them.